# How do I run a full system upgrade using old RPM?

Tags: fedora, rpm

I had an old NAS server which is running Fedora release 12 (yes). The last system update was in 2012. Consequently, all packages are extremely outdated, and many core commands aren't even available (`man`, `sudo`, `passwd`, ...). I looked into the documentation and apparently the command is `rpm -U <package>`. However, that `<package>` seems to be not the package name, but the path to an `.rpm` file. There are no `.rpm` files on the entire system. I have tried updating the example package `perl` using all of these commands (all gave `No such file or directory` errors):

```bsh
rpm -F perl
rpm -F perl.rpm
rpm -F perl-5.10.0-82.fc12.armv5tel
rpm -F perl-5.10.0-82.fc12.armv5tel.rpm
rpm -F `rpm -q perl`
```

Even apart from that, how can I run a full system upgrade? Every command seems to require a specific package. Furthermore, neither `yum` nor `dnf` are installed.

`neofetch --stdout`:

```
OS: Fedora release 12 (Constantine)Fedora release 12 (Constantine)Fedora release 12 (Constantine) armv6l
Kernel: 2.6.31.6-fast-20110114
Uptime: 1 hour, 25 mins
Packages: 282 (rpm)
Shell: bash 4.0.33
Terminal: /dev/pts/0
CPU: Oxsemi NAS (2)
Memory: 81MiB / 248MiB
```

Or should I just ditch the OS?

Comment: Is the nas a system you built or it's provided by the manufacturer?

Comment: It came with the current OS settings.

Answer (score 2):

RPM files *are* software packages, in their not-installed state.

In order to update, you would need to get the RPM files appropriate for your OS release **and CPU architecture**, place them all into a directory somewhere, then run `rpm -U *.rpm` in that directory.

Since your NAS server is apparently using `armv5tel` architecture, you cannot use RPMs intended for x86 hardware, as the CPU architecture is completely different. And it looks like the packages for old Fedora releases for ARM are getting hard to find.